# aasm ruby gem: super user without restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, aasm

Given the next model using the **aasm** gem:

```
class Job
  include AASM

  aasm do
    state :sleeping, :initial => true
    state :running, :cleaning

    event :run do
      transitions :from => :sleeping, :to => :running
    end

    event :clean do
      transitions :from => :running, :to => :cleaning
    end

    event :sleep do
      transitions :from => [:running, :cleaning], :to => :sleeping
    end
  end
end
```

I have 2 types of users on my web application (regular users, and super users). I need super users type, beeing able to call the event they want. Like calling #run on a job with state=cleaning.

So, as I understand, what I need is to resolve the transition's **from** at runtime. If the user is a superuser, the **from** would be all the states, but if the user is not a super user, each from would have different states.

Is there any clean way to do that? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Making decisions in a model layer based on `current_user` has always been considered a code smell, so a couple of clean ways to achieve your goal could be:

1. To implement some inheritance, like:

   ```
   CommonUserJob < Job
     # move your current AASM validations here
   end

   AdminJob < Job
     aasm do
       event :run do
         all_states = Job.aasm.states.map{|i| i.name}
         transitions :from => all_states, :to => :running
       end
       # other events here in same manner
     end
   end
   ```

   Then you should get a `CommonUserJob` or `AdminJob` instance based on your user's role and call a state change.
2. To implement some composition (refer to [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)), which would mean you move your role-specific `aasm` code to modules and extend `job` object with a particular one at a runtime.

Note that both of this suggestions leave your base `Job` class without any `aasm` validations at all. This seems to contradict a common Rails way, but follows a [DCI paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677916/what-is-dci-and-how-can-it-fit-with-rails), which states that we should decouple what the system is (domain model) from what the system does (functionality). Base class instances should still be able to get its current state though.